# Let $f,g \in {\mathscr R[a,b]}.$ If $\int^{b}_{a}f^2=0,$ then $\int^{b}_{a}fg=0.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g \in {\mathscr R[a,b]}.$ If $\int^{b}_{a}f^2=0,$ then $\int^{b}_{a}fg=0.$

I have shown that $2|\int^{b}_{a}fg|\leq t\int^{b}_{a}f^2 + \frac{1}{t}\int^{b}_{a}g^2, t>0.$ Hence how do I show $\int^{b}_{a}fg=0?$ Thank you.

Comment: since it is not an improper integral it is also Lebesgue-integrable, then f is 0 a.e. and the claim follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**  $t\int^{b}_{a}f^2=0$ and now let $t\to\infty$...

Comment: Look at me, answering a question about integration! Hah! I still can't believe it.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. 
I have established that $|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2).$ How do I further show that 
$|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|^2)\leq (\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2)?$

Comment: I'm... not sure?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo error. I meant, $|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|)^2\leq (\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2).$

I have just shown that $(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|)^2\leq(\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2).$ Now, it remains to show 
$|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|)^2.$

Comment: Do you know that $|\int f|\leq\int|f|$?

Comment: Well, that's about as far as my train of thoughts can take me when it comes to integration. ;-) Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'm done! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can show that if the integral of a positive function is zero then this functions is a.s. zero.

$$ \int f^2d\mu \ge \int_{f^2>\epsilon}f^2d\mu$$ but

$$ 0= \int_{f^2>\epsilon}f^2 d\mu > \epsilon \mu(\{f^2>\epsilon\})$$

Making $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ you have $\mu(\{f^2>0\})=0$. This show what you want.

Hope this can help.

Comment: This is perfectly OK in the context of Lebesgue integration, of course. But here we talk of Riemann integrals, which make sense only on Peano-Jordan measurable sets. Is it obvious that $\{f^2>\varepsilon\}$ is Peano-Jordan measurable?

Comment: Ok, ok. The proof maybe it is not right in the context of Riemann integrals, but the result is still true, right? Once Riemann integrable implies Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Yes, of course.